# Booting into safe mode without keys

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

I have a jailbroken iPhone 6s running iOS 12.2. It was working well until I used Chimera to jailbreak and it went into a reboot and then got stuck in the Apple logo. (I used Chimera multiple times to jailbreak after a reboot and it had worked pretty well)

I have been trying to boot into safe mode with the volume up key but doesn't seem to work. I don't want to use iTunes to restore because it will upgrade to 12.4 and I won't be able to jailbreak it again.

Is there any other way to boot into safe mode other than the keys? Or is there a way to reset the iPhone with 12.2 itself?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Unfortunately your first paragraph is a little confusing. You start with *"I have a jailbroken iPhone 6s running iOS 12.2. It was working well until I used Chimera to jailbreak and it went into a reboot and then got stuck in the Apple logo. "*. So, you had a jailbroken iPhone that was working well, but then you went to jailbreak it and it got stuck at the reboot? So, was it jailbroken initially or not? And can you clarify *"I used Chimera multiple times to jailbreak after a reboot and it had worked pretty well"*? Are you talking about on different devices?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Basically, I used Chimera to jailbreak it. But, on every reboot, I would have to jailbreak again. This reboot and then jailbreak process was working fine. But, yesterday I tried the Chimera jailbreak again and it is since then stuck at the Apple logo.

Answer (score 1):

After restarting into non-jailbroken mode, there is an option in the Chimera app to jailbreak with tweaks disabled. (this is Chimera's equivalent of safe mode)